# Bash script to filter out the files in home directory above 100 kb and ask whether to remove them or archive them

Tags: bash, archive

Please, can someone help me with the following script. It is supposed to find all the files above 100kb in the home directory and ask about each of them whether they should be added to an archive or deleted. 
I found on Stack Overflow only one similar problem, where the solution was `rsync -a --max-size=100kB sourcedir destdir` but my problem is how to stop script to let the user decide about every file what to do with it. For the time being it shows the question as many times as many files there are in the home directory but I cannot enter any answer. 
The script is supposed to keep (in a separate file) a record of times and names of deleted files.

```
#!/bin/bash
find ${HOME} -size +100k|
while read filename; do
      read -p "Delete the file (y for yes) or add to the archive (n dla no)?" yn;
      case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) tar -c archiwum.tar $filename; echo "$filename `time`">> record ;;
        [Nn]* ) rm $filename;;
         * ) echo "Please answer yes or no";;
      esac
      done
    while true; do
```

Comment: Read from the `tty`: `read -p "Delete ..." < /dev/tty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you need your `read` command to read from the terminal, but the while loop to read from your command:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read filename; do
      read -u 3 -p "Delete the file (y for yes) or add to the archive (n dla no)?" yn
      case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) tar -c archiwum.tar $filename;;
        [Nn]* ) rm $filename;;
         * ) echo "Please answer yes or no";;
      esac
done 3<&0 < <( find ${HOME} -size +100k )
```

What this does is redirect stdin (file handle 0) to file handle  (`3<&0`). Then `read` reads from file handle 3 (`-u 3`), and the while loop reads from it's stdin, which is the find command.

@gniourf_gniourf's solution in the comment will also work to make `read` read from the terminal and not from the input to the `while` loop.